# How to create URL in wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, methods, get

I am new to wordpress plugin and I have started a few lines of code. What I am wondering now is on how to create a URL that will listen for incoming data using GET method.

I would like to have a URL like:

http://www.mydomain.com/process.php

This process.php file contains a php code that saves a value from the parameter.

Example I have a javascript on the same website that call this URL like:

http://www.mydomain.com/process.php?value=1&country=US

Inside process.php is a simple script that will save the value to the table like:

```
<?php
$value = $_GET["value"];
$country = $_GET["country"];

$wpdb->insert( 'wp_mytable', array( 'value' => $value, 'country' => $country ), array( '%s', '%s' ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First all include wordpress wp-load.php in your process.php. and define global
   variable $wpdb;
   by including wp-load.php file and define global variable $wpdb. Now you can able to call 
   the all wordpress functions in ajax file.

Comment: So, when I call the URL it should be called like: http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/process.php?value=1&country=US? Is this possible? I am thinking it should create a clean URL like http://www.mydomain.com/process/?value=1&country=US